# Compare/check multiple columns in multiple sheets and find the unmatched values

Tags: comparison, libreoffice-calc

I have two sheets in libreoffice calc, both sheets have same columns, i need to compare these sheets column values(multiple columns) and need to check rows are equal, if not equal then need to differentiate the unmatched values.

How can i do this?Please help me to get this done.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the easiest way is to put the sheets in different ods files and use the built-in document comparison feature to compare both: Menu `Edit` -> `Compare Documents...`.